# Changes not appearing when modifying Android system apps

Tags: android

I have downloaded the CyanogenMod source tree and am trying to add a feature to one of the screens.

I have added the new UI element and added some small bits of code to set it up in `onCreateView` of the screen in question.  (For debugging, I also added a `Log.d` message.)  After building the app with `mm Settings` from the tree root, I first tried to install it with `adb install`, but the package manager complained about an invalid install location.  So instead I copied the file `out/target/product/generic/system/priv-app/Settings.apk` to my device's `/system/priv-app` folder.  I killed Settings and restarted it, but my changes did not appear, and no message was printed in logcat.

I even tried rebooting the device, but I could not observe any of the changes I made to Settings.  I did notice a `.odex` file produced alongside the `.apk` that I'm interested in, but I think that file is one of the ones generated before the APK.  My changes are definitely being compiled, because typing gibberish into the XML or Java files causes the build system to complain.

What are the necessary steps to develop on one of the system apps in Android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do this is to use `adb`.  Manually copying the app using the file manager does not seem to work, but pushing the file does.  Run the following commands:

```
adb root
adb remount
adb push Settings.apk /system/priv-app/Settings.apk
```

These commands a) restart the `adb` daemon on the device as root, b) remount the system partition as read/write, and c) push the new file.

The first two commands' effects persist until a reboot.